# Ghosts/almost dead had their hearts ripped out and now have to pump them by hand and never sleep?

Tags: story-identification

I know I didn't come up with this but I can't remember where it's from.

The story is that I think some soldiers or knights maybe were walking through a forest and were attacked by someone/something. Their hearts were ripped out but they didn't die so now they walk around the forest, carrying and pumping their hearts, not living or dead.

I feel like it was a story told to the main character, probably in a book but maybe not, as a sort of incidental/local colour tale that was not relevant to the plot.

Please help, where have I got this from?

Comment: Do you remember when you encountered this and in what language? This may help narrow it down. Take a look at [this page](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) just in case you remember any other details and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 6):

Lungs, not hearts, but I think you're remembering The Breathless Ones from **The Golden Compass** aka **Northern Lights** by Philip Pullman.

*Breathless Ones are half-killed warriors who are unable to die. Tartars cut ribs of the warriors and damage their lungs in such a way that the victims don't die and continue to survive as a punishment. They can only survive by their daemons pumping them manually.*

http://hdm.wikia.com/wiki/Breathless_Ones

Comment: Yes! That's right, thank you.